# Cython: ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python-2.7, cython

I have compiled some Cython code and
call it within a Python script.
This worked until recently. Now it's not
working any more and gives the error

ImportError: DLL load failed: initialization of a DLL file failed.

I'm on Win7 64Bit, Anaconda distribution 2.0.1. Recompiling the Cython code didn't help.

```
import time
import Implied_Vola

underlyingPrice=5047
strikePrice=4600
interestRate=0.03
daysToExpiration=218
price=724.5
optiontype='Call'
start=time.time()
vola= Implied_Vola.Implied_Vola(underlyingPrice,strikePrice,interestRate,daysToExpiration,price,optiontype)
end=time.time()
time=float(end-start)
```

Any idea what to do? How to check if it compiles using Windows SDK for compilation and how to check the Cython version in Ipython?